# How to use stackdriver client from GAE standard environment?

Tags: google-app-engine, stackdriver

Execution of this this line:

```
logging = LoggingOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService()
```

On Google App Engine standard environment instance results with:

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: exception occurred while calling backend method (SystemService.java:398)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.channels.spi.SelectorProvider is a restricted class. Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at java.nio.channels.spi.SelectorProvider.<clinit>(SelectorProvider.java)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:59)
    at io.grpc.netty.Utils$DefaultEventLoopGroupResource.create(Utils.java:187)
    at io.grpc.netty.Utils$DefaultEventLoopGroupResource.create(Utils.java:171)
    at io.grpc.internal.SharedResourceHolder.getInternal(SharedResourceHolder.java:121)
    at io.grpc.internal.SharedResourceHolder.get(SharedResourceHolder.java:91)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory.<init>(NettyChannelBuilder.java:311)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder$NettyTransportFactory.<init>(NettyChannelBuilder.java:280)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyChannelBuilder.buildTransportFactory(NettyChannelBuilder.java:230)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:239)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingChannelProvider.createChannel(InstantiatingChannelProvider.java:123)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingChannelProvider.getChannel(InstantiatingChannelProvider.java:110)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ProviderManager.getChannel(ProviderManager.java:105)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelAndExecutor.create(ChannelAndExecutor.java:67)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ClientSettings.getChannelAndExecutor(ClientSettings.java:81)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.spi.v2.ConfigServiceV2Client.<init>(ConfigServiceV2Client.java:131)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.spi.v2.ConfigServiceV2Client.create(ConfigServiceV2Client.java:122)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.spi.DefaultLoggingRpc.<init>(DefaultLoggingRpc.java:141)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingRpcFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:68)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingRpcFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:62)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getRpc(ServiceOptions.java:503)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingImpl.<init>(LoggingImpl.java:96)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:43)
    at com.google.cloud.logging.LoggingOptions$DefaultLoggingFactory.create(LoggingOptions.java:38)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.getService(ServiceOptions.java:490)
```

Is there any way to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the v2 api of google-api-services. Explanation:

---

Google provides two sets of supported libraries for interfacing with their cloud services.

1. **Google API Client Libraries**[1] (google-api-services): older libraries that provide a programmatic overlay on top of each API's REST interface
2. **Google Cloud Libraries**[2] (google-cloud): alpha/beta libraries that are based on gRPC. They are allegedly much more performant, but are NOT supported in Standard Appengine (found this little note in their github page.. [3]) because of network security limitations on gRPC.

Each set of libraries now has a v1 and v2 set of apis for both sets of libraries (v1 is discontinued).

1. **google-api-services** v2 documentation[4]
2. **google-cloud** v2 documentation[5]

---

Sources:

- Main docs page: https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/client-libraries-explained
- [1]: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/
- [2]: http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.10.0/index.html
- [3]: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java
- [4]: http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.10.0/apidocs/index.html
- [5]: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/logging/v2beta1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/logging/v2beta1/package-summary.html